# dimple.js - show gaps in line chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js

I would like to draw a line chart that will show gaps for missing data for any dates along the x-axis.   I looked at this example here http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3035090 and then looked at the dimple source.  i essentially attached a new draw function to series.plot.draw that was the same as in line.js but replace the getLine function with one below.  I see the new draw function getting called, but still does not seem to work however...as no gaps are appearing where missing data exist for certain dates.

```
getLine = function (inter, originProperty) {
    return d3.svg.line()
        .defined(function (d) { return d.y != null; })
        .x(function (d) { return (series.x._hasCategories() || !originProperty ? d.x : series.x[originProperty]); })
        .y(function (d) { return (series.y._hasCategories() || !originProperty ? d.y : series.y[originProperty]); })
        .interpolate(inter);
};
```

Any thoughts on how to solve this?